# Swiping right to return to previous screen on iOS app- inbuilt function?

Tags: ios, swift

Is the ability to swipe right and return to the previous view controller an in-built function like clicking back on a web browser, or something that has to be coded in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is built in as `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` on `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Great stuff, so I don't actually need to do anything then since UINavigationController is loaded with my initial ViewController?

Comment: @RDowns that is correct. If this solved your problem make sure to accept!